# Cannot access files in my localhost for phpmyadmind using xampp

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

when trying to access my localhost files inside my htdocs for xampp/phpmyadmin. Runnning Mac OS 10.15.7, and Xampp 8.0.0. I am able to successfully access phpmyadmin and start all required services.
I have added 'Require all grant' to my httpd-xampp.conf file but i still get this error message.
Thank you to any help.

Error Code Reads:
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/8.0.0 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.0

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: @tadman I edited and added the error message sorry about that.

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log? It sounds to me like your file system permissions don't permit the webserver process to read the files. Perhaps they're owned by root or set to permissions like 600. In MacOS, you can check a file's permissions with "Get Info" and expanding the `Sharing & Permissions` area at the very bottom.